# IP camera stream on a canvas in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I have been asked to solve what seems like a simple task in javascript but I am not well versed in it, so to speak.  I need to take an IP camera stream and put it onto a three.js canvas.

I started with this example which uses a webcam instead of an IP camera: 
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Webcam-Texture.html

In it there is a video tag that looks like this:

```
<video id="monitor" autoplay width="160" height="120" style="visibility: hidden; float:left;"></video>
```

Which I believe is called later:

```
    video = document.getElementById( 'monitor' );
```

So, like I said, I don't know much about javascript, but I was hoping it would be relatively simple to replace the call to the webcam in this example to a call to an IP camera.  I tried simply replacing the  tag with a new one:

```
<video controls src="http://[wowza-address]:1935/live/camera.stream/playlist.m3u8">
</video>
```

But that did not work.  Obviously it is more complicated than I originally expected.  Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: You may want to research about CORS... http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
var imageDetect = document.createElement('img');

imageDetect.src = BaseURL + File;

            function render() {

            imageContext.drawImage( imageDetect, 0, 0 );

            if ( texture ) texture.needsUpdate = true;
            if ( textureReflection ) textureReflection.needsUpdate = true;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```